# Add Gatsby blog to specific URL in a React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redirect, gatsby, forwarding

I have two separate apps. One is a react app that is deployed at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the other is a completely separate blog app built with Gatsby.

I would like users to be able to visit [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) and see the blog app without using a redirect that would change the URL.

Both apps are hosted as separate firebase projects, is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature called [`pathPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/) which purpose is what you are looking for.

You just need to set it in the main Gatsby configuration file (`gatsby-config.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
}
```

Following the previous example, a link to `/test-1` will be rewritten as `/blog/test-1` automatically.

Another important consideration is to understand that all your building commands (build and serve) will need to be respectively flagged as:

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
gatsby serve --prefix-paths
```

*During development paths don't need to be prefixed.*

In-app linking is handled automatically by [Gatsby's `Link`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/) component.

For pathnames you construct manually, there’s a helper function, `withPrefix` that prepends your path prefix in production.

Additional resources:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/asset-prefix/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/deploying-to-gitlab-pages/#add-path-prefix-to-gatsby

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, but unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't solve my issue. I have two completely separate apps, a react website, and a gatsby blog app. I want to be able to navigate to /blog in my react website and be taken to the gatsby app. Ideally the user would feel as though they are still on the same website if this makes sense?

Comment: It solves your issue as long as your Gatsby site will be available under /blog. The rest of the configurations under production environment or local environment (development) belongs to the server-side/docker customization where you have not provided any details about possibilities, initial configuration, etc since it's an extremely broad question that needs extra information for your side

Comment: Yeah so I guess my question is more along the lines of how do I make my blog app available under /blog in my separate app? I'm not sure what other details would be useful, both apps are simple frontend apps hosted in separate firebase projects under the same account, and I have a standard domain registered through AWS which I can configure DNS, etc for.